# flutter - clear the widget cache

Tags: flutter

When I leave a page when I work with flutter and then re-enter it, the old values are saved.

I don't want this to happen.

For example, when I first enter:

```
int number = 1;

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

bool donus = true;

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<Todo> sorular = new List<Todo>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(donus);
    super.initState();
    getTodos();
  }

  bool pressAttention = true;
  String ileri = "İleri", geri = "Geri";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {number++;
   print(number);
```

output:1

Second entry to the page:
output:2

I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please rename your title to English, as this is an english-speaking site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your `number` variable is outside the scope of your page and its state.

`number` is essentially static or global, and its lifetime is tied to your application's. Tighten up its scope so that it is declared within your state class and initialise it in your `initState` method (for private non-final variables).

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

bool donus = true;

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<Todo> sorular = new List<Todo>();
  int _number;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _number = 1;
    print(donus);
    super.initState();
    getTodos();
  }

  bool pressAttention = true;
  String ileri = "İleri", geri = "Geri";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _number++; // You probably don't want to increment every time you build,
             // but I have no idea what you're using `number` for.
  print(_number);
```

Your `donus` variable is also global, which is unlikely to be what you had intended. Dart is an object-oriented language; refer to the [language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) for more details on classes, scope, etc.